# showing differentiability at a point

Tags: calculus

I am trying to show taht the following functions is diferentiable at x = $\sqrt{3}$.

$$ 
\alpha(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            x^2-3 & \quad x < \sqrt{3}\\
            0 & \quad x \geq \sqrt{3} 
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

To show it is differentialbe at the given point, the following limit must exist:

$$ \alpha'( \sqrt{3} ) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{ \alpha( \Delta x + \sqrt{3} ) - \alpha( \sqrt{3} ) }{\Delta x } = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0 } \frac{ \alpha( \Delta x + \sqrt{3}) }{\Delta  x }$$

Can we argue that as $\Delta x \to 0^- $, then $\alpha( \Delta x + \sqrt{3} )= \sqrt{3}^2 - 3 = 0 $ ?? since $\sqrt{3} + \Delta x < \sqrt{3 }$ ?

Comment: I don't think that it is differentiable though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the limit
$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{ \alpha( \Delta x + \sqrt{3} ) - \alpha( \sqrt{3} ) }{\Delta x }$$
you'll have to distinguish between the right- and left-hand limits.

For $\Delta x \to 0^-$, we have $\sqrt{3}+\Delta x < \sqrt{3}$ so in that case
$$\alpha(\Delta x + \sqrt{3}) = (\Delta x + \sqrt{3})^2-3 = \Delta x^2+2\sqrt{3}\Delta x$$
which means the left-hand limit becomes
$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0^-} \frac{ \alpha( \Delta x + \sqrt{3} ) - \alpha( \sqrt{3} ) }{\Delta x } = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0^-} \frac{\Delta x^2+2\sqrt{3}\Delta x-0}{\Delta x } = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0^-} \left( \Delta x+2\sqrt{3}\right) = 2\sqrt{3}$$
On the other hand, for $\Delta x \to 0^+$, we have $\sqrt{3}+\Delta x > \sqrt{3}$ so in that case $\alpha(\Delta x + \sqrt{3}) =0$:
$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0^+} \frac{ \alpha( \Delta x + \sqrt{3} ) - \alpha( \sqrt{3} ) }{\Delta x } = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0^+} \frac{0-0}{\Delta x } =0$$
The two limits differ, so the function is **not** differentiable at $x=\sqrt{3}$. Or, put differently: the function has a left and a right derivative at $x=\sqrt{3}$, but their values are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Let's change $\;\Delta x\;$ for $\;h\;$ , for simplicity:

$$\sigma'(\sqrt3)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sigma(\sqrt3+h)}h=\begin{cases}0,\,&h>0\\{}\\\lim\limits_{h\to0^-}\frac{(\sqrt3+h)^2-3}h=\lim\limits_{h\to0^-}\frac{2h\sqrt3+h^2}h=2\sqrt3,\,&h<0\end{cases}$$

and since the limit doesn't exist the function isn't differentiable at that point.